# How to make space between scrollable view and buttons in android layout?

Tags: android, android-layout

When text content inside the TextView is larger than the view, the text goes beneath the buttons (which are sticked at the bottom), despite the fact that I tried setting `marginButton for both TextView and ScroleView:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
    tools:context="com.shinyapp.shiny.DetailActivity"
    tools:showIn="@layout/activity_detail">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
        android:text="Title"
        android:id="@+id/title"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />


    <ScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"

        >

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="txtBody"
        android:id="@+id/body"
        android:layout_below="@+id/title"
        android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
        android:padding="10dp"
        android:paddingBottom="20dp"
        android:maxLines = "1000"
        android:scrollbars = "vertical"
        android:textSize="22sp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
        />
    </ScrollView>

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Next"
        android:id="@+id/nextBtn"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom = "true"
        android:onClick="nextWord"
        style="@style/indexButtonStyle"
        />

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Prev"
        android:id="@+id/prevBtn"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/shareBtn"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom = "true"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:onClick="prevWord"
        style="@style/indexButtonStyle"
        />

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Index"
        android:id="@+id/indexBtn"
         android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        style="@style/indexButtonStyle"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom = "true"

        />
</RelativeLayout>
```

I'm wondering what is the idiomatic way to solve this issue?

Comment: try to use a LinearLayout instead of a RelativeLayout around the whole thing it could fix the issue

Comment: did you try setting android:layout_above="@+id/nextBtn" for ScrollView

Comment: @innich it does not fix the issue.

Comment: @Deletescape with LinearLayout, I get `Wrong orientation? No orientation specified, and the default is horizontal, yet this layout has multiple children where at least one has layout_width="match_parent" less... `

Comment: @Karlom Wait I am sorry read your code again my suggestion does not make sense... Sorry for taking your time